# How can I create a CASE Statement BETWEEN Two Dates?

Tags: case, looker-studio

I am looking to do a [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement in a [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) to identify dates as holidays, and have tried:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN
    FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%M%D", date) BETWEEN 20190218 AND 20190219 OR
    FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%M%D", date) BETWEEN 20220220 AND 20220222
    THEN 'presidents_day'
  ELSE NULL
END
```

I am having trouble formatting the date correctly to use the `BETWEEN` statement and I am getting the error:

> Invalid formula - Operator "BETWEEN" doesn't support TEXT BETWEEN NUMBER AND NUMBER. Operator "BETWEEN" supports ANY BETWEEN ANY AND ANY.

[image: attempt_case]

Data Set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jga264bj_XG596FKjKaYyoqnskvWTlDgj9LCQEckEbY/edit?usp=sharing)):

| date |
| --- |
| 17 Feb 2019 |
| 18 Feb 2019 |
| 19 Feb 2019 |
| 20 Feb 2019 |
| 19 Feb 2022 |
| 20 Feb 2022 |
| 21 Feb 2022 |
| 22 Feb 2022 |
| 23 Feb 2022 |

Expected output:

| date | Date_CASE |
| --- | --- |
| Feb 17, 2019 |  |
| Feb 18, 2019 | presidents_day |
| Feb 19, 2019 | presidents_day |
| Feb 20, 2019 |  |
| Feb 19, 2022 |  |
| Feb 20, 2022 | presidents_day |
| Feb 21, 2022 | presidents_day |
| Feb 22, 2022 | presidents_day |
| Feb 23, 2022 |  |

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5c31cd7b-9ee6-440d-897a-b15dc7e86282) report

Answer (score 0):

Using the `BETWEEN` operator in conjunction with the [`DATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9697009) function ("*Creates a date*" in the `YYYY, MM, DD` format) would create the required [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement (where `date` represents the date field):

```sql
CASE
  WHEN 
    date BETWEEN DATE(2019, 02, 18) AND DATE(2019, 02, 19) OR 
    date BETWEEN DATE(2022, 02, 20) AND DATE(2022, 02, 22) 
    THEN "presidents_day"
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/736764d1-6a29-40cd-80dd-1646d50a0088) report (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iUgMnEsnZfDpE9bis287XC6LV4LcUiwXyHaXy1gMgc4/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]